# View Rest Export includes comments in json

Tags: views

View Rest Export returns a JSON with comments. How can I disable comments?

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: This is either caused by a contributed module or custom code changing the response.

Comment: It seems a debugging module that shows some rendering details as HTML comments. They should not be in JSON data.